# prove or give counter example, for every holomorphic function on the unit disc there is $f(z)=z$

Tags: complex-analysis

let f be a holomorphic function on $D=\{z\in \mathbb C:|z|<1\}$. and let $f$ be continuous on $cl(D)$ and $f[D]\subseteq D$.
Prove or give counter example,
$\exists z\in D\mathrm{.f(z)=z}$

Comment: What about $f(z) = 2$?

Comment: @Sten you're right, I forgot to add a condition.

Comment: What is the meaning of $f[D]$?

Comment: shortcut for ${y|\exists x \in D. f(x)=y}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counter example: Let $a$ with $0<|a|<1$ and $$f(z)=\frac{z-a}{1-\bar a z}.$$

Comment: What is the fixed point here?

Comment: @Noobmathematician The equation $f(z)=z$ gives that $z=\pm a/|a|$, which do not lie in $D$.

Comment: Thank you @Pythagoras